# Getting coordinate of intersection of line and plane with only distances

Tags: geometry

There are equilateral triangle on surface (z=0) and plane. How can point coordinates on plane when one point of triangle is on plane? Followings are known information.

There is equilateral triangle on surface. ($z$=0, distance between to points is $S$)
One point of triangle is on the plane.
Distance of other two points are known. (Making perpendicular with plane, each $S_2$, $S_3$)

With these information, how can get (x,y,z) of point that not on plane?
I found exactly what I want on Patent (US 5,241,518 FIG.5, (4.31)~(4.33)) with formula, but I can't catch that. Can I get some hint or relative articles?
[Figure.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPF7S.png)

Given formular:
$x$ = $S_3$($S_2$-$S_3$)/$S$
$y$ = -($S_2$$S_3$+$S_3^2$)/($S$$\sqrt3$)
...

But I have no idea how to validate above formulars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plane in space is defined by an equation like $ax+by+cz+d=0$. The vector $(a,b,c)$ is the normal direction. If $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ then $ax+by+cz+d$ for a point *not* on the plane will be the signed perpendicular distance. So assuming $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ you have

\begin{align*}
ax_1+by_1+cz_1+d&=0 \\
ax_2+by_2+cz_2+d&=s_2 \\
ax_3+by_3+cz_3+d&=s_3
\end{align*}

Without the condition $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$, the above is an under-defined linear system of equations. You will find a one-dimensional space of solutions. So you get

$$(a,b,c,d)=(a_0,b_0,c_0,d_0)+\lambda(a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1)$$

Now plug this into $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ and you have a quadratic equation in $\lambda$, with two solutions.

Note that the perpendicular distance above is signed. So the approach described works if $P_2$ and $P_3$ are on the same side of the plane. If they are on opposite sides, you have to make one of these negative.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how can I get x_3 with only S2, S3 and distance of each P? Patent what I mentioned above wrote x = S3(S2-S3)/S (S is distance of each P), I followed on hand with your answer and try few times, but I have no idea about handle S and so couldn't reach to result.. Can I have more instruction or any tips?

Comment: @hsl: I thought $S_2$ was the distance between plane and $P_2$, likewise $S_3$. So what's $S$? $x_3$ in my formula would be the $x$ coordinate of $P_3$, as you wrote that exact coordinates of triangle are known. If you had provided a link to the patent document including figures, I might have looked at that, but as it is, I've found two copies without figures and then lost interest.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/013nh) This is figure what I mentioned. $S$ is distance between each transducers on figure. $S_2$ and $S_3$ are known information. I want find small x, y, z, without coordinates of triangle. I'm sorry about ambiguous description.

Comment: @hsl: If you *don't* have coordinates for the triangle, but you only have distances, then you don't have any way to align a coordinate system, and can't expect to get coordinates for anything. In the meantime I also noticed your question title asks about a line-plane intersection which I didn't find in the question. I suggest you edit your question, make it clear what exactly you know and what you want to find out, and also include the link to the figure.